# How to change the warning message to display in popup alert in joomla 3.1

Tags: joomla

I would like to change the displaying of warning message in joomla 3.1 which comes after logged in, to display in alert box. Below is the message which i would like to show in alert box. I have used com_users components for my user login page.

**Warning

Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet.**

Please anyone help on this..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The message you provided is a language string which is located in:

```
root/languages/en-GB/en-GB.lib_joomla.ini
```

In that file, search for which is around line 60 I believe:

```
JLIB_LOGIN_AUTHENTICATE="Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet."
```

Comment: Thanks lodder but i would like to display this message as popup alert box. Can u please suggest me how to make over that